# How would I add speech bubble to the left and right of div w/o adding a child-div?

Tags: html, css

The speech bubble right here gets placed on top of the div, how would I get it to be placed on the left or right of the div?

How would the rotations look and how would the placement work?

CSS:

```
<style>
    .speech-bubble {
        position:relative;
        margin-top: 5px; 
        float:right; 
        color: black;
        background-color:white;
        padding: 7px;
        border: 1px solid;
        border-color:red;
        border-radius: 4px;   
    }
    .speech-bubble:before,
    .speech-bubble:after {
        content: " ";
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        top:-8px;
        left:25px;
        z-index:2;
        width: 1px;
        height: 0;
        overflow:hidden;
        border: solid 10px transparent;
        border-top: 0;
        border-bottom-color:#FFF;
    }
    .speech-bubble:before {
        top:-10px;
        z-index:1;
        border-bottom-color:red;
    }
</style>
<div class="speech-bubble">   
    awe
    fawefawefawef<br/>
    aawefawef
</div>
```

[CodePen Link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrvzdY)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the values in the following lines:

```
.speech-bubble:before,
.speech-bubble:after {
    top:-8px;
    left:25px;
}
.speech-bubble:before {
    top:-10px;
}
```

Or use this [generator](http://ilikepixels.co.uk/drop/bubbler/).